# libTiMidity for MS-DOS

Tags: c, dos

Following the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745079/quickbasic-4-5-gravis-ultrasound-library), which involves finding/writing a Gravis Ultrasound MIDI library for QuickBasic under DOS (DOSBox), I would like to ask this:

Is it possible to compile [libTiMidity](http://libtimidity.sourceforge.net/) under MS-DOS? If so, what are the requirements?

Comment: I suspect that compiling libTiMidity for MS-DOS won't really help you. Why not use the MIDI library you linked to in your previous answer? DOSBox will most likely render the sound with TiMidity anyway. if you don't like the sound for same, try installing better soundfonts, [here's an explanation of how to do this on ubuntu](http://macilatthefront.blogspot.com/2010/05/timidity-and-dosbox-in-ubuntu-1004.html)